# how do the onStart and onResume methods work in android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

So im creating a texting UI for android. The way its handling message threads is that when i hit send it sends the message, creates a new message thread and then adds this message to the corresponing instance of my conversation view.

ConverseView is an activity that only has an onCreate(Bundle) method. This method creates an adapter and populates the adapter with values from a ArrayList. Array list gets a message added to it when the user hits send. However these do not show up in the views.

I believe that the problem is, the activity is being created then im adding a message, and the ListView is not updated. How can i fix this.

Comment: Please see the documentation of the Activity Lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle In particular, print out a copy of the diagram which illustrates how things work and fix it to the wall next to your computer screen. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ArrayAdapter adapter;` backed by an `ArrayList`. To update the data in the list after modifying your ArrayList just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more information on the lifecycle.

Essentially, `onStart(Bundle state)` is call after the Activity has started. This means that the activity is alive and responding to a) the application and b) to Android itself.

`onResume(Bundle state)` means that the activity is about to be displayed to the screen. This is where you should finialize any UI stuff you have to do.

As for your data not showing up, you need to call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to push your adapter redrawing. Your adapter will not update (graphically) without this call.